# Single Page App - CSS3 width/height 100% not effective because Bootstrap doesn't define static value of body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a single page web app and I am also using boostrap 3.0. What I am having an issue with is making a div section, ie `<div id="nameContainer">`, fill up the entire viewport as if it was it's own page. Instead, the next sibling `<div id="nameContainer">` will show up on the view port. I thought I could fix this with css position, width, and height attributes but I am not having success. How do I make each `<div id="nameContainer">` fill the entire viewport as if it it's own page? I have my own css page load last so my custom CSS override any bootstrap behavior.

**EDIT:** the width: 100% and height: 100% is ineffective because the body is not defined in static values(non percentage). How do I get this size/assign the size of body so the percentages of the viewport are correct?

section of index.html:

```
<body class="container">
    <div id="lightbox">
        <div id="exitButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">Exit</div>
        <div class="well col-lg-8" id="messageBox">
            <h3 class="messageBox" >Performing operation...</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="lead">
        Filler to use as position: absolute
    </div>
    <div id="shareImageContainer">
        <div class="well col-md-3 titleBox">
            <div>
                <h1>Share Image<br><small>Share image all in one step</small></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form id="shareImageForm">
            <div class="form-group btn-group-ls well col-md-5">
                <legend>Region</legend>
                <input class="form-inline" type="radio" name="region" id="IAD0" value="IAD" checked>
                <label for="IAD0" class="btn btn-default region">Virginia</label>
                <input class="form-inline" type="radio" name="region" id="ORD0" value="ORD">
                <label for="ORD0" class="btn btn-default region">Chicago</label>
                <input class="form-inline" type="radio" name="region" id="DFW0" value="DFW">
                <label for="DFW0" class="btn btn-default region">Dallas</label>
                <input type="radio" id="HKG0" name="region" value="HKG">
                <label for="HKG0" class="btn btn-default region">Hong Kong</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group well col-md-5">
                <label for="producerUsername">Producer Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="producer_username" id="producerUsername" placeholder="Enter producer's username" required>
                <label for="producerApiKey">Producer Api Key</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="producer_apikey" id="producerApiKey" placeholder="Enter producer's api key" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group well col-md-5">
                <label for="consumerUsername">Consumer Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="consumer_username"id="consumerUsername" placeholder="Enter consumer's username" required>
                <label for="consumerApiKey">Consumer Api Key</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="consumer_apikey" id="consumerApiKey" placeholder="Enter consumer's api key" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group well col-md-5">
                <label for="imageUuid">Image UUID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="image_uuid" id="imageUuid" placeholder="Enter images's image Uuid" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="addMemberContainer">
        <div class="well col-md-3 titleBox">
            <div>
                <h1>Add Member<br><small>Add a member to be shared</small></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form id="addMemberForm">
            <div class="form-group btn-group-ls well col-md-5">
                <legend>Region</legend>
                <input class="form-inline" type="radio" name="region" id="IAD5" value="IAD" checked>
                <label for="IAD5" class="btn btn-default region">Virginia</label>
                <input class="form-inline" type="radio" name="region" id="ORD5" value="ORD">
                <label for="ORD5" class="btn btn-default region">Chicago</label>
                <input class="form-inline" type="radio" name="region" id="DFW5" value="DFW">
                <label for="DFW5" class="btn btn-default region">Dallas</label>
                <input type="radio" id="HKG5" name="region" value="HKG">
                <label for="HKG5" class="btn btn-default region">Hong Kong</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group well col-md-5">
                <label for="producerUsername">Producer Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="producer_username" id="producerUsername" placeholder="Enter producer's username" required>
                <label for="producerApiKey">Producer Api Key</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="producer_apikey" id="producerApiKey" placeholder="Enter producer's api key" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group well col-md-5">
                <label for="imageUuid">Image UUID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="image_uuid" id="imageUuid" placeholder="Enter images's image Uuid" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group well col-md-5">
                <label for="consumerAddId">Consumer/Member account id number to add</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="consumer_tenantid" id="consumer_tenantid" placeholder="Enter member account id number" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#lightbox {
    display: none;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 85;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

.messageBox {
    padding-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}




body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#lead {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}   

[id*="Container"] {
    position: relative;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to add width and height to html also.

```
body, html {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` is a lazy hack which defeats the purpose of CSS, especially when you use it at the top most level of the DOM since now it makes any child CSS that needs altered widths or heights harder to make